# How does Powershell display variable operation work?

Tags: windows, powershell

In powershell

```
$a = 4;
$a
```

will write 4 to the output stream.

```
Write-Ouput $a
```

writes 4 to output stream

Can you explain which operation is better performance wise if all I want to do is write variables to output stream?

Comment: the 2nd  - `Write-Output` - is apparently slower since it appears to send its output tot he same place as the bar $Var` does. the speed difference is NOT important until one gets to hundreds or thousands of repetitions, tho. [*grin*] ///// for a good idea of what is involved, try this article ... >>> Get-PowerShellBlog: Let’s Kill Write-Output — https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/06/lets-kill-write-output.html

Comment: If you want to do testing yourself, you can see the speeds of the commands with `measure-command {$a}` and `measure-command{write-output $a}` or `measure-command{<any-command>}`. As far as differences go, I don't think there are any besides the fact that `write-output` has more output options. You can also prints strings with `"$a and other string"` but it doesn't have the same options as `write-output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see what's in your variable, you should use a dollar sign with the name of your variable. This is most likely the fastest method to display the value of the variable.

**UPDATE**

**Short answer**: You should use just `$a` in order to write data in the output stream. It's the fastest way to do that.

**Long answer with explanation**:
If you write something like `$a`, then it goes directly to the output stream of the current PowerShell process, in other words, it goes to the output pipeline. This is because in PowerShell you have in general only three types of possible statements:

1. Definition statement: They are everything that you can define in your code for further use like functions or classes.
2. Assignment statement: You assign a value to a variable.
3. Putting-in-the-pipeline statement: everything else except 1 and 2.

Example for definition statements:

```
Function foo($bar)
{
    #do stuff here
}
```

Example for assignment statements:

```
$foo = 'bar'
```

Example for putting-in-the-pipeline statement:
It is exactly what you asked! If you write `$a`, then it will be written to the output pipeline. That’s it.

Now about `Write-Output`. According to this [code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Write-Object.cs) from the official PowerShell repository, it's just a wrapper for another PowerShell Cmdlet, namely for [WriteObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#overloads). Therefore, the invocation of `Write-Output` costs more time then the invocation of `WriteObject`.

As Lee_Dailey mentioned in the first comment to your question, there is a wonderful article [Let’s Kill Write-Output](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/06/lets-kill-write-output.html) written by Mark Kraus in his blog. At first sight it may seem that it doesn't have much to do with your question, but this article explains what happens with objects that you wrote in your script and when they are not surrounded with different "printing functions" like `Write-Out`. There you can also find examples of how to "bypass" the use of the `Write-Out` in different situations that it brings advantages in performance.

I also recommend to read these two articles from Microsoft's DevBlogs:

1. [Understanding Streams, Redirection, and Write-Host in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)
2. [Weekend Scripter: Welcome to the PowerShell Information Stream](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/)

They will definitely help to understand how streams are implemented and how they work in PowerShell.

Comment: Here my goal is to write data to the output stream. I couldn't find any documentation on how $a works. Mainly looking for differences b/w $a vs write-output $a and which approach is better.

Comment: @SaiSaketh Yes you are right. Unfortunately, I can not find any more detailed information on the subject than what I have already written. So far I've only found this article, which explains a little how the streams work in PowerShell: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

Comment: @SaiSaketh Unfortunately I don't know if you get notifications when I update my answer, so I point this out with this comment.